# Jquery append items to container on resize

Tags: jquery

I have a list of inline menu items that are part of a responsive build, I would like for the menu items that overflow the list container to be appended to another element and then appended back when the list container is not overflowing.

This is the best I could come up with and I'm stumped at this stage.

[Fiddle][1][1]: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyharry/s2bas09m/18/

```
var visible = false;

// Detect overflowing items
function getOverflows(){

    var listWidth = $("ul").outerWidth(); // Get list width
    var listItems = $ ("ul li"); 

    // Get child item width
    var listChildWidth = 0;
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        listChildWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    // Add dropdown menu
    function createDropdown(){
        if (listWidth < listChildWidth){
            if(!visible){
                $("ul").after("<div class='dropdown'></div>");
                visible = true;
            }
        }
    }createDropdown(); 

    $(listItems).each(function(i) {
        listCo = $(this).position();
        listItemWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        listTotal = listCo.left + listItemWidth;
        if(listCo.left > listWidth){
            var elem = $(this).sort(sortItem);

            function sortItem(a, b) {
                return a.className > b.className;
            }

            $('.dropdown').append(elem);

        }else{
            var elem = $(".dropdown li").sort(sortItem);

            function sortItem(a, b) {
                return a.className > b.className;
            }
            $('ul').append(elem);
        }
    });       
}getOverflows();

$(window).resize(function() {    
    getOverflows();
});
```